# differences between behavior get_option vs get_site_option in multisite

Tags: multisite, options

I am converting a bunch of sites to multisite and I am confused about the behavior differences between get_option and get_site_option.

It appears that get_site_option actually means "get_network_wide_option" and get_option means "get_option_for_this_site", and the same for the update versions.

Given this, if a plugin wants to have discrete settings for each site, it needs to use get_option and update_option. On the other hand, if it wants option values to be constant across all sites, then use the get_site_option version.

Is my understanding of this correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, `get_site_option()` is for data about the whole network.

The irritation comes from a mixed vocabulary: what was a **site** once is a **network** nowadays, and what was a **blog** once is now a site in a network.

`wp_get_sites()` for example is from version 3.7, it fetches sites in a network, not all networks in an installation. So a **site** in `wp_get_sites()` is not the same as a **site** in `get_site_option()`.

For plugin that should be used in a single-site installation **or** as network plugins only, you can always use `get_site_option()`, because on a single site it will fall back to `get_option()`.

One important difference is: normal options are loaded automatically on every requests, so you will hit the cache with `get_option()`. Site options are not loaded automatically, only some core options. See `/wp-includes/option.php wp_load_core_site_options()`.

To store information for all sites in all networks you have to use a custom table or pick one network in the current installation.